# Return alsoempty months with null value in last 12 months mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL which checks on subscriptions in the last 12 months. 
The problem is, that if there is no subscription in a certain month, it will not show in the results.
Take for example the following structure for the vacancies table:

```
+------------+---------------------+--------+------------+--+--+
| vacancy_id |     create_time     | org_id | is_deleted |  |  |
+------------+---------------------+--------+------------+--+--+
|          1 | 2018-04-06 08:09:48 |      1 |          0 |  |  |
|          2 | 2018-02-06 08:09:48 |      1 |          0 |  |  |
|          3 | 2017-08-06 08:09:48 |      1 |          0 |  |  |
+------------+---------------------+--------+------------+--+--+
```

and the vacancy subscriptions like this:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
| subscr_id |  msg  | vacancy_id |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|         1 | test  |          1 |
|         2 | test2 |          3 |
+-----------+-------+------------+
```

Now my query is this:

```
SELECT
                               YEAR(v.create_time) as vacyear, MONTH(v.create_time) as vacmonth, COUNT(*) as totalsubscriptions
                            FROM `vacancies` as v 
                            LEFT JOIN `vacancy_subscriptions` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
                            WHERE
                               (v.create_time >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH)))
                               AND v.is_deleted = 0
                               AND v.org_id = 1
                            GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth
                            ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC
```

Which works and gives the correct result in the case there is a subscription for that month.
In this example, how do I let the output contain all months?

```
2018-04
2018-03
2018-02
2018-01
2017-12
2017-11
2017-10
2017-9
2017-8
2017-7
2017-6
2017-5
```

UPDATE:

I tried the solution suggested below by user @Gordon Linoff and created a table containing month_id's with their names like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar_months` ( `month_id` INT(8) NOT NULL, `en_abbr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `en_long` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `nl_abbr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `nl_long` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And I inserted data in there like this:

```
month_id = 1
en_long = 'January'
...
month_id = 2
en_long = 'February'
...
```

Then I modified the query to become this:

```
SELECT
   YEAR(v.create_time) as vacyear, MONTH(v.create_time) as vacmonth, COUNT(*) as totalsubscriptions, cm.nl_long
FROM `calendar_months` as cm
LEFT JOIN `vacancies` as v on cm.month_id = month(v.create_time)
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_subscriptions` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
WHERE
   (v.create_time >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH)))
   AND v.is_deleted = 0
   AND v.org_id = 1
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth
ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC
```

Result stays the same

UPDATE 3:

```
SELECT
   YEAR(v.create_time) as vacyear, MONTH(v.create_time) as vacmonth, COUNT(*) as totalsubscriptions
FROM `vacancies` as v 
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_subscriptions` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
WHERE
   (v.create_time >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH)))
   AND v.is_deleted = 0
   AND v.org_id = 1
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth
ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC
```

This query gives correct amount results: 
[image: results first query]

If i then use the query as suggested by @Gordon Linoff below, which is:

```
SELECT YEAR(m.dte) as vacyear, MONTH(m.dte) as vacmonth,  
       COUNT(vs.vacancy_id) as totalsubscriptions
FROM (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -11 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -9 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -4 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) as dte
     ) as m LEFT JOIN
     vacancies v
     ON v.create_time >= m.dte AND
        v.create_time < m.dte + interval 1 month AND
        v.is_deleted = 0 AND v.org_id = 1 LEFT JOIN
     vacancy_subscriptions vs 
     ON v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
WHERE m.dte >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth
ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC;
```

I am getting the following result (the amount is much lower as it should be):
[image: query 2 results]

Answer (score 1):

The safest solution is to have a calendar table or use a derived table with the months you want.  That then becomes the first table in the `LEFT JOIN` and the `WHERE` conditions move to an `ON` clause.

In many cases, though, the `WHERE` clause is filtering out months that would otherwise be in the result set.  If that is the case for your data, then you have a simpler solution.  Simply move the `WHERE` conditions to the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT YEAR(v.create_time) as vacyear, MONTH(v.create_time) as vacmonth,  
       SUM(v.is_deleted = 0 AND v.org_id = 1) as totalsubscriptions
FROM vacancies v LEFT JOIN
     vacancy_subscriptions vs 
      ON v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
WHERE v.create_time >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth
ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC;
```

I should emphasize that this does not always work -- it requires that each month of interest have *some* record in your table.  If it does work, it is normally the simplest solution.

EDIT:

Otherwise, you need a solution that is some variant on:

```
SELECT YEAR(m.dte) as vacyear, MONTH(m.dte) as vacmonth,  
       COUNT(vs.vacancy_id) as totalsubscriptions
FROM (SELECT date('2017-05-01') as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2017-06-01') as dte UNION ALL
      . . .
      SELECT date('2018-04-01') as dte
     ) m LEFT JOIN
     vacancies v
     ON v.create_time >= m.dte AND
        v.create_time < m.dte + interval 1 month AND
        v.is_deleted = 0 AND v.org_id = 1 LEFT JOIN
     vacancy_subscriptions vs 
     ON v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
WHERE m.dte >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth
ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC;
```

"Some variant" takes into account that you might have some other method of calculating the list of months.

Comment: A fixed calendar table isn't the safest option in a multi user environment.. What if a other admin also needs to use the calendar table and the both off you are messing up the others results
constantly.. if you want to use a calendar table use a temporay table which is only visible/useable by the persoon who made it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . How would two users reading a table "mess each other up"?

Comment: "How would two users reading a table "mess each other up"?" By adding records the other doesn't need so the other deletes the records again end so on until one off the DBA's shouts who is deleting from that table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . You misunderstand.  A calendar table should be part of the database or the server, maintained by the DBA.  Users should not be modifying it.  `SELECT` queries do not add rows to a table.

Comment: "You misunderstand. A calendar table should be part of the database or the server, maintained by the DBA. Users should not be modifying it." read mine first comment iam talking about a other admin which is ofcource a DBA.. "SELECT queries do not add rows to a table." i know how MySQL works trust me..

Comment: The point you make in your 2nd alinea  is not the case for me, there are months with simply no entry for the user. So I tried modifying it to match your first part, I updated my question

Comment: @Dennis . . . I don't know what a "user" is, but as long as *some* row in the table is during the month, this will work.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff is there any way to also make this work if there is not a row in the table during that month? Just so the total amount would be 0 for that month, but it still always gives 12 rows back (one for each month in the last 12).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your help. After using the query you provided, I get results being far lower than what they should be

Comment: The `join` to the months derived table should not be changing the counts (I mean, except for the obvious of inserting new rows for the missing months).

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for the help! I edited the main question and put the both queries and their results as resulted